# 12.04 giving problems with IOGear GPSU21 print server

Tags: 12.04, printing

all.

I had an old WinXP box I was using as file server and print server and it has failed. I'm trying to set up an IOGear GPSU21 print server with the same printer.

My 12.04 laptop printed to this printer without issue when it was on the XP box. When printing through the GPSU21, I get the following status, and the printing fails: "Processing - Error writing spool: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT"

This laptop dual-boots to Win7, and I can print to the printer through the GPSU21 fine there.

I followed the suggestions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/announce.html?t=1658955 but they didn't help. (Those suggestions are to add "Allow all" directives in several of the location tags in the /etc/cups/cupsd.conf file.)

Any suggestions on where to go from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have and use that very same print server. First, find out in the administration pages of your router the IP address of the print server. Set the router to reserve the IP address assigned so that the address doesn't change.

Next, I set up the printer with the Device URI of ipp://192.168.1.xx:631/lp1. Substitute the reserved IP address for 192.168.1.xx here. Then select the make, model and driver for your printer and print a test page.

A very few printers are subject to a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/945028 If you get the mentioned error, then try the Device URI of ipp14://192.168.1.xx:631/lp1.

The *lp1* part comes from the manual of the IOGear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, chili555, but printing this way gives this status error:

Processing - Printer does not support IPP/2.0, trying IPP/1.1.

This is followed by:

Idle - Ready to print.

But nothing prints.

Comment: Well, third time's the charm, apparently. I printed a test page a third time, and that one came out. Go figure.

So, apparently this is now working. Thanks for the answer, chili555!

Comment: If you continue to get the "...Printer does not support IPP/2.0, trying IPP/1.1..." message, try ipp14. I'm glad it's working.